# htaccess rewrite general help for the helpless

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm completely helpless when it comes to htaccess. I've tried and tried and can't seem to understand it.

I'm trying to rewrite

`http://somedomainname.com/index.php?route=product&make=Samsung&model=1001SHD`

to the link below

`http://somedomainname.com/Samsung-1001SHD-TV-Set`

The `TV-Set` would be a static addition to each URL. It will be the same across the entire site.

Any tips, pointers, code, or a finger in the right direction would be very much appreciated it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?route=product&make=([^\s&]+)&model=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2-TV-Set? [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^-]+)-TV-Set/?$ index.php?route=product&make=$1&model=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: thanks for the response, it's functioning however returning a 404 error.

This is the url it's rewriting, and it's doing it properly

http://somedomain.com/index.php?route=product&make=Samsung&model=1011SHD

To be clear, the rewrite is working properly, even adding the TV-Set, however, it results in a 404 page..

Comment: Just updated it, this is the result

http://somedomainname.com/Samsung-1001SHD-TV-Set

This obviously isn't the real URL. The real URL contains a space in the model, or %20 as it's displayed in the URL bar.

Comment: WORKING! Thank you so much

Is there a way you could possibly post a variant that would be without the Make? 

The end result being 

http://somedomainname.com/1001SHD-TV-Set

Where samsung doesn't exist, as there would be some redundancies ...

If anything, I'd prefer it actually be without the manufacturer if that's the only way. 

Sorry to bother, new thought that came across my mind lol